# Pre C++11 equivalent to explicitly deleting constructors ( Type(const Type&) = delete; )

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Is there a way to achive that behaviour on compilers that don't support C++11 ?

```
class Meow
{
public:
    Meow(const Meow&) = delete;
};
```

Making the constructor private is not a solution, because then you can do something like that:

```
class Meow
{
private:  
    Meow(const Meow&);

public:
    Meow();

    void doSomething()
    {
        Meow kitty;
        Meow secondKity(kitty); // allowed
    }
};
```

If the constructor is marked as `deleted` the above is not possible.

Comment: Don't understand the up vote. OP said "Making the constructor private is not a solution, because then you can do something like that:" . Did not even try to compile and run the code looks like.

Comment: @jagann that may have been a bad example (still his example is "illformed, no diagnostic required"). But the technique wont work if the copy constructor call is elided and the call happens within the class. .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Making the constructor private is the pre-C++11 solution. Your second code is not valid because the copy constructor doesn't have a definition (presuming you don't give it a definition elsewhere). Yeah, it's not the best solution, but that's why `= delete` was introduced.

You may want to use [`boost::noncopyable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable) to be more explicit about it, but it only does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily emulate that with a **private, not defined** copy constructor.
Instead of a nice error message you'll get a linker error as the copy constructor won't be found.

Another alternative is `boost::noncopyable` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable), which wraps this technique in a nice little helper class.

Comment: Unfortunately, the compiler is allowed to omit calling the copy constructor in many cases, so that the undefined reference to the copy constructor will not be detected by the linker in such cases.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Even if the compiler elides copies that copy constructor/assignment operator still has to be accessible!

Comment: i am not talking about accessibility

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I know you're talking about eliding calls to copy operations. **BUT** you're missing that even if the compiler omits these calls, they must still be accessible!

Comment: Version 1: compiler **does not optimize** => `linker error`, Version 2: compiler **does remove copies**, yet **still has to check for access control** => PENG, **compiler error**

Comment: *Version 2: compiler does remove copies, yet still has to check for access control => PENG, compiler error*, no. As the questioner states correctly, access checking is not enough when the copy happens within the class itself. You seem to still think I am talking about access control rather than the "no definition" part of  it.